# How can I extract the OAuth consumer key from a Rails request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth

When an OAuth signed request is made to a Rails 3 app, I can see the OAuth consumer key in amongst the other values in `request.headers["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]`. What is a better way to access it? I'm using the [OAuth](https://github.com/oauth/oauth-ruby) gem.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this section in the OAuth specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.5.1), the `Authorization` header is the preferred way of sending OAuth protocol parameters. The specification does make allowances for sending protocol parameters in a form encoded body or in the request URI, if the request meets certain requirements.

To answer your question: parsing the `Authorization` header is a must for any OAuth provider. But you may also look for it (and other protocol parameters) amongst "normal" parameters, you will never find them in more than one place,